# Learning to cluster using one sample per class

Tags: svm, learning

I have a question regarding an idea. I know many ML algorithms and I know how they work and perform. But I have an idea which I believe in should be similar to one of the current available methods.

The idea is there are 2 clusters of points in space with n dimensions (n large). Based on the context we expect the clusters to be fairly separated. Now the question is I need an algorithm which takes the data, number of clusters, and 1 sample per clusters as input, and then tries to cluster the rest of the data. The main feature here is the fact that the algorithm starts with 1 sample per class, and then it must go on finding very similar points first and so on.

Does anyone have any idea which algorithm or method is the most similar method to the thing I'm looking for?

Comment: Obviously, you will start randomly with one sample per class and if it groups similar points to it's group, then those random points have to be fairly apart at the first place(doesn't work like that) for the best clustering or you have to update the cluster centers at each step (being done in k-means). I guess you are trying to redefine k-means clustering.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at **hierarchial clustering**, this is similar to what you want. Normally they start with either all the samples as their own clusters and then recursively find two clusters that when merged reduce the intercluster distance the least (some kind of metric that you can define) or the other way around where you have one cluster and you split a cluster in a way that increases the intercluster distance the most.

What you could do is start with your samples as individual clusters and keep adding the sample that is closest to one of your clusters greedily. This is also similar to **label propagation**.

Another way is to base it on **k-means** by taking all the samples as cluster centers, assign all your other points to the closest centers and update your cluster centers. A problem with this approach is that your original cluster samples could actually end up in another cluster, which you would need to either constrain in some way or accept.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1 sample per cluster **as input**, then you are **not facing a clustering problem**, but a **classification** one, where your training dataset is comprised of 1 sample per class.

With the setup you described, the most direct approach would be 1-nearest neighbor, that is, [k-nearest neighbors algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) with $k=1$.

I think any other machine learning classification algorithm you may try on your training dataset would probably end up with the similar results as 1-nn. Anyway, if you don't have have a test dataset, you cannot assess the *correctness* of your *model*.